# Accessing control-m jobs from linux command line

Tags: control-m

I have access to Linux servers (client) where control-m jobs runs and only control-m agent is installed. Is there a command line utility to access jobs from Linux command line from the client machine? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Control-M utilities can be executed from servers (Linux/Windows) with Control-M agents installed:
`_exit`
`_sleep`
`ag_diag_comm`
`ag_ping`
`ctmagcfg`
`ctmunixcfg`
`ctmwincfg`
`set_agent_mode`
`ctmcontb`
`ctmcreate`
`ctmdefine`
`ctmdeffolder`
`ctmdefsubfolder`
`ctmfw`
`ctmloadset`
`ctmkilljob`
`ctmorder`
`ctmudly`
`ctmvar`
`ecactltb`
`ecaqrtab`
`migrate_dc`
On a linux server they can typically be found in your exe directory, for example: `/home/ctmagent/ctm/exe`.
I suggest looking at the Control-M Utilities guide to find out more information about what each of these utilties can do.